# Play sound on collision

Tags: html

Here is my code:

```
var snd = new Audio("dog_barking.mp3");

if(gameObjects[catRow][catColumn] === DOG)      
{
  snd.play();
  endGame();
}
```

I'm trying to get a sound to play when the player (The cat) runs into the Dog. So, When the player runs into the dog the game ends and plays a sound. But, nothing plays. The game ends like it should but, no sound plays. Do I need a function in my code or is it something else like volume?

I am new at coding and I'm doing this for a project.
I'm also using HTML5/JavaScript. And I'm using Notpad++.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Does the browser's JavaScript console output any errors? Can it find the audio file?

Comment: Check your JS console for any errors, it could lead to the source of the problem, for example, if the file was not found.

Comment: Its not giving any errors like the audio hasn't been found except for "unexpected token" its been giving me for my script tag. But, besides that nothing seems wrong and everything works.

Comment: Do you have a variable called `DOG`? If not, try changing DOG to "DOG"

Comment: I do have a variable for DOG it is "var DOG = 2;" The two is for the area on the map the dog image will be positioned. And I did that but, I got a "expected identifier" error on it. Should I change all DOG to "DOG"?

Comment: Not all browsers can play MP3 files. Which browser are you using? Check this compatibility table: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Comment: I am using the code in IE but, I can switch it to Chrome or Firefox easily.

Comment: @Nick: IE should be able to play MP3 files. Another question: Has the sound fully loaded before you try playing it? If it hasn't loaded yet, it won't play.

Comment: @d13It has downloaded completely. I even re-downloaded it again. I got the sound file from OpenGameArt.com.